# Nesting filters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My array of objects is given below

```
let full_list = [
            {
                "pid": 1,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '9'},
                    {"item_id": '10'},
                    {"item_id": '12'}
                ]
            },
            {
                "pid": 2,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '33'},
                    {"item_id": '22'},
                    {"item_id": '65'}
                ]
            },
           {
                "pid": 3,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '5'},
                    {"item_id": '2'},
                    {"item_id": '1'}
                ]
            },
        ];
```

Based on the selectedIds my array of objects is to be filtered.
Can someone help me with this.

I tried nested filtered I could not get the output

```
selectedIds=[9,33,1,5];
```

Expected Output is given below

```
           [
            {
                "pid": 1,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '9'},
             
                ]
            },
            {
                "pid": 2,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '33'},
                 
                ]
            },
           {
                "pid": 3,
                "items":[
                    {"item_id": '5'},
                    {"item_id": '1'}
                ]
            },
        ];
```

How can I achieve this output in typescript?

```
 let filteredList=  fullList.filter((x) => x.items.filter((y) => selectedIds.indexOf(y.item_id) >-1) );
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you tried. Show code.

Comment: I have added what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need "map" the list to get the only values of items, then filter by items.length. You can use a function like:

```
   filterList(full_list:any[],selectedIds:any[]){
    return full_list
       .map(x=>({
          pid:x.pid,
          items:x.items.filter(i=>selectedIds.indexOf(+i.item_id)>=0)
        }))
        .filter(x=>x.items.length)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
const selectedIds=[9,33,1,5]
let filteredList = fullList.map(el => {
  pid: el.pid,
  items: el.items.filter(item => selectedIds.includes(Number(item.item_id)))
})
```

Comment: It is better ot use `parseInt` instead of `Number` constructor

Comment: This is not working for me when I implemented this in angular.It says unused labels pid and items

Comment: @mohammedfahimullah please share print screen of error message

Comment: There are a few reasons why this doesn't work, but it's all syntax. fullList vs full_list, and the curly braces are interpreted as code blocks instead of object delimiters. Try `let filteredList = full_list.map(el => ({
  pid: el.pid,
  items: el.items.filter(item => selectedIds.includes(parseInt(item.item_id)))
 }
));`